# Export json to file from Neo4j databse using PHP

Tags: php, json, neo4j, neoxygen

I used for that the following command line:

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {"statements":[{"statement":"match n return n"}]}
```

when I set this query into a PHP variable, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Neoxygen\NeoClient\Exception\Neo4jException' with message 'Neo4j Exception with code "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax" and message "Invalid input ':' in C:\wamp\www\PhpProjectNeo4j1\vendor\neoxygen\neoclient\src\Extension\AbstractExtension.php on line 88
```

Could you please explain to me how can I add this command in PHP?

Comment: What does your code look like now? What is the PHP code that gives you this exception?

Comment: Also, have you looked on line 88 of AbstractExtension.php, as the exception suggests?

Comment: My code now is: `$queryx = ":POST /db/data/transaction/commit {\"statements\":[{\"statement\":\"match n return n\"}]}";

  $resultx = $client->sendCypherQuery($queryx)->getResult();`

Comment: At line 88 I have the following code: `  public function checkResponseErrors($response)
    {
        if (isset($response['errors']) && !empty($response['errors'])) {
            throw new Neo4jException(sprintf('Neo4j Exception with code "%s" and message "%s"', $response['errors'][0]['code'], $response['errors'][0]['message']));
        }
    }
`

Comment: @jjaderbeg if you know any method which can export Json file from Neo4j databse using PHP, pleaaaaase let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the NeoClient documentation ?

The single usage is :

`$result = $client->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n) RETURN n')->getResult();`

If you want to export to json, there is no magic in the client, just use the nodes objects returned, create an array and encode it to json :

```
$nodes = [];
foreach ($result->getNodes() as $node) {
  $nodes[] = [
            'id' => $node->getId(),
            'labels' => $node->getLabels(),
            'properties' => $node->getProperties()
            ];
}

var_dump(json_encode($nodes));
```

EDIT :

In order to have the result object, you need to have the ResponseFormatting service enabled :

example :

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addDefaultLocalConnection()
    ->setAutoFormatResponse(true)
    ->build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Bu i get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getNodes() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\PhpProjectNeo4j1\index.php

Comment: can you post your code used for 1. building the client 2. send the query and output the json.